# What is the best way to query ContactsContract to get Emails, Phones and Addresses at the same time?

Tags: android, contactscontract

As far as I have found, there doesn't seem to be a way to join tables together. I know that I can query for a CommonDataKinds table for Phone, StructuredPostal (address) or Email, but I can't seem to find a way to query for all three of them at once.

I only get a Cursor that has either one of them but not an aggregate projection.

Anybody have some advice on how I can achieve something like this?

Here is what my get StructuredPostal query currently looks like:

```
public static Cursor getAddressCursor(ContentResolver contactHelper, String startsWith) {
    logger.v("getAddressCursor");
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        if (startsWith != null && !startsWith.equals("")) {
            cursor = contactHelper.query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE '" + startsWith + "%'",
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        } else {
            cursor = contactHelper.query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

How would I go about aggregating Phone and Email into this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this method:

```
public void readContacts(){
     ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
     Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);

     if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                System.out.println("name : " + name + ", ID : " + id);

                // get the <span class="IL_AD" id="IL_AD4">phone number</span>
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                                       new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                      String phone = pCur.getString(
                             pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                      System.out.println("phone" + phone);
                }
                pCur.close();


                // get email and type

               Cursor emailCur = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);
                while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
                    // This would allow you get several email addresses
                        // if the email addresses were stored in an array
                    String email = emailCur.getString(
                                  emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                    String emailType = emailCur.getString(
                                  emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));

                  System.out.println("Email " + email + " Email Type : " + emailType);
                }
                emailCur.close();

                // Get note.......
                String noteWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                String[] noteWhereParams = new String[]{id,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
                        Cursor noteCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, noteWhere, noteWhereParams, null);
                if (noteCur.moveToFirst()) {
                    String note = noteCur.getString(noteCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.NOTE));
                  System.out.println("Note " + note);
                }
                noteCur.close();

                //Get Postal Address....

                String addrWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                String[] addrWhereParams = new String[]{id,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
                Cursor addrCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                            null, null, null, null);
                while(addrCur.moveToNext()) {
                    String poBox = addrCur.getString(
                                 addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POBOX));
                    String street = addrCur.getString(
                                 addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET));
                    String city = addrCur.getString(
                                 addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY));
                    String state = addrCur.getString(
                                 addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION));
                    String postalCode = addrCur.getString(
                                 addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE));
                    String country = addrCur.getString(
                                 addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY));
                    String type = addrCur.getString(
                                 addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE));

                    // Do something with these....

                }
                addrCur.close();

                // Get Instant Messenger.........
                String imWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                String[] imWhereParams = new String[]{id,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
                Cursor imCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                        null, imWhere, imWhereParams, null);
                if (imCur.moveToFirst()) {
                    String imName = imCur.getString(
                             imCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.DATA));
                    String imType;
                    imType = imCur.getString(
                             imCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.TYPE));
                }
                imCur.close();

                // Get Organizations.........

                String orgWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                String[] orgWhereParams = new String[]{id,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
                Cursor orgCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                            null, orgWhere, orgWhereParams, null);
                if (orgCur.moveToFirst()) {
                    String orgName = orgCur.getString(orgCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.DATA));
                    String title = orgCur.getString(orgCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE));
                }
                orgCur.close();
            }
        }
   }
}
```

You will get phone number, email, notes, postal address etc.

Comment: Damn, is there any way to get it from one big Data table?